# How can I reshape a Mat 2D to vector<vector<Mat>>?

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to convert a Mat whose dimensions are [2000][256] and I want to convert this to a `vector<vector<mat> >` with dimensions [256][20][10][10]. In Matlab, it is possible to do `reshape(Mat2d, 10, 10, 20, 256)`; I would like to do the same here.

Comment: afaik there is no obvious way to do this reshaping, so you have to specify how it is supposed to be done (aka write the code by hand)

Comment: well, in matlab it is posible to do reshape(Mat2d, 10, 10, 20, 256), i would like to do the same

Comment: Have you looked at any libraries like Eigen http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page that cover linear algebra? (in particular http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReshapeSlicing.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution:

```
vector<vector<Mat>> 
reshape2D4D(Mat &A, int dim1, int dim2, int dim3, int dim4)
{
    vector<vector<Mat>> B;
    for (int i = 0; i<dim1; i++) {
        B.push_back(vector<Mat>());
        for (int j = 0; j<dim2; j++)
            B[i].push_back(Mat(dim3, dim4, CV_64F, Scalar::all(1)));
    }
    Mat in = A.reshape(1, 1);
    Mat subImg; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            subImg = in(cv::Range(0, 1), cv::Range(100*j, 100*j + 100));
            subImg.reshape(10, 10);
            B[i][j] = subImg;
        }
    }
    return B;
}
```